# Repeat the last value over time

Tags: powerbi, dax, interpolation

I have a table with power plant capacities in different years. There are only entries when something changes in the capacities. In the years not listed, the last value applies.

| Plant | Year | Capacity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cottam | 2003 | 800 |
| Cottam | 2009 | 600 |
| Cottam | 2015 | 800 |
| Drax | 2000 | 600 |
| Drax | 2005 | 1200 |
| Drax | 2010 | 1800 |
| Drax | 2013 | 1200 |
| Drax | 2020 | 0 |
| Ironbridge | 2007 | 500 |
| Ironbridge | 2015 | 0 |

Now I would like to transform the initial table, so that I also have values for all years in between and can display them in a stacked column chart, for example. The result should look like shown in the table below. Marked in yellow are the numbers from the initial table.

[image]

Comment: This is a data shaping exercise. Are  you sure you want DAX rather than M/Power Query? Would a calculated table in DAX work?

Comment: This is of cause a simplified example and I'll have to see how to integrate the solution im my rather complex power plant database. And I guess DAX will work, too.

Comment: Ron's answer is the right way to go.

Comment: But a DAX solution is easier, see my answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to solve this (more easily) in **DAX**:

1. Prerequisite is separate **Calendar** table with a 1:many relation on the year

```
Calendar = 
SELECTCOLUMNS(
   GENERATESERIES(
       MIN(Plants[Year]),
       MAX(Plants[Year])
   ),
   "Year", [Value]
)
```

2. Next calculate the **Last Given Capacity** per year

```
Last Given Capacity = 
VAR current_year = 
    MAX(Calendar[Year])
VAR last_capacity_year =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(Plants[Year]),
        'Calendar'[Year] <= current_year
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(Plants[Capacity]),
        Calendar[Year] = last_capacity_year
    )
```

3. Finally put it all together in a **Stacked Column Chart** with

```
X-axis: 'Calendar'[Year]
Y-axis: [Last Given Capacity]
Legend: 'Plants'[Plant]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily in the Query Editor in M code.

To reproduce, paste the code below into a blank query:

```
let

//change next line to reflect your actual data source
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45Wcs4vKUnMVdJRMjIwMAZSFgYGSrE6qOKWQMoMU9zQFEm9S1FiBUS1AZJqhChIraERurAhSLEhhhmGxlhVG4FUQ8Q8i/LzkooyU9JTIcabAylTA6xyYGcCZWIB", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Plant = _t, Year = _t, Capacity = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Plant", type text}, {"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Capacity", Int64.Type}}),

//generate Table of all years
    #"All Years" = Table.FromColumns(
            {List.Numbers(List.Min(#"Changed Type"[Year]), List.Max(#"Changed Type"[Year])- List.Min(#"Changed Type"[Year]) + 1 )}),

//Group by Plant
// Aggregate by joining with the All Years table and "Fill Down" to replace blanks with previous year.
// then expand the grouped column
    #"Group by Plant" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type","Plant",{
        {"Joined", each Table.FillDown(Table.Join(#"All Years","Column1",_,"Year",JoinKind.FullOuter),{"Capacity"})}
    }),
    #"Expanded Joined" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Group by Plant", "Joined", {"Column1", "Capacity"}, {"Column1", "Capacity"}),

//Replace nulls with zero's
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Expanded Joined",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Capacity"}),

//Pivot on year
//  then set the data types
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Value", {{"Column1", type text}}, "en-US"), 
        List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Value", {{"Column1", type text}}, "en-US")[Column1]), "Column1", "Capacity"),

//set data type
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Pivoted Column", 
        List.Transform(List.Sort(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column"),1), Order.Ascending), each {_, Int64.Type}))
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

***Edit Note:***
Actually, to create the graph in Power BI, you do **NOT** want to pivot the data, so the shorter code:

```
let

//change next line to reflect your actual data source
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45Wcs4vKUnMVdJRMjIwMAZSFgYGSrE6qOKWQMoMU9zQFEm9S1FiBUS1AZJqhChIraERurAhSLEhhhmGxlhVG4FUQ8Q8i/LzkooyU9JTIcabAylTA6xyYGcCZWIB", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Plant = _t, Year = _t, Capacity = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Plant", type text}, {"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Capacity", Int64.Type}}),

//generate Table of all years
    #"All Years" = Table.FromColumns(
            {List.Numbers(List.Min(#"Changed Type"[Year]), List.Max(#"Changed Type"[Year])- List.Min(#"Changed Type"[Year]) + 1 )}),

//Group by Plant
// Aggregate by joining with the All Years table and "Fill Down" to replace blanks with previous year.
// then expand the grouped column
    #"Group by Plant" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type","Plant",{
        {"Joined", each Table.FillDown(Table.Join(#"All Years","Column1",_,"Year",JoinKind.FullOuter),{"Capacity"})}
    }),
    #"Expanded Joined" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Group by Plant", "Joined", {"Column1", "Capacity"}, {"Year", "Capacity"}),

//Replace nulls with zero's
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Expanded Joined",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Capacity"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Value",{{"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Capacity", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

Then, in Power BI, you can generate this:

[image]

***Note:***
The code below presents the Table FillDown / Table Join sequence from the first code using variables and more comments. Should be easier to understand (might be less efficient, though)

```
...
{"Joined", each 
            let 
            //join the subtable with the All Years table
                #"Joined Table" = Table.Join(#"All Years", "Column1", _, "Year", JoinKind.FullOuter),

            //Fill down the Capacity column so as to fill with the "last year" data
            //   since that column will contain a null after the Table.Join for years with no data
                #"Fill Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Joined Table",{"Capacity"})
            in 
                #"Fill Down"
    }
...
```

Comment: I find it difficult to decompose the combined Group - Join - Filldown step, so I can't really apply your sample solution to my more complex problem.

Comment: @Peter I don't understand. But it is certainly the case examples that don't represent the real problem may lead to solutions that work for the example, but not for the real problem.

Comment: Not quite my point. Rather, it looks as if the group-fill-join step was constructed subsequently, just like many Excel users copy their intermediate formulas into the final one - possibly to save space. However, this makes these results difficult to understand and adjust, if necessary.

Comment: @Peter No, it was constructed that way. But from the inner to the outer formulas. On the various forums, what I've observed is that most of the knowledgeable contributors seem to avoid using variables, so I've just copied them unless things are super complex.  I'll edit the question to include that section broken down a bit and commented.